# When using CASE inside a WHERE clause, without ELSE, what is meant by NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

```
declare @Name varchar(45)

SELECT
     *
FROM
     table law
WHERE
     --law.emp = case when isnumeric(@Name) = 1 then @Name else null end
     law.emp = case when isnumeric(@Name) = 1 then @Name end

     or coalesce(law.lname + ', ' + law.fname, '') like '%' + @Name + '%'
```

My question here is focusing on the `CASE` statement when it evaluates to something other than a numeric value...

If `@Name` is anything other than a numerical value, what is really happening?  `law.emp = null`???  If so, it shouldn't return any results anyway, because the proper syntax is something like `where law.emp is null`, right?

So, just for clarification, my `emp` column doesn't actually contain any nulls.

I'm just trying to figure out what is really happening to my `WHERE` statement when `@Name` evaluates to something not numeric...

What actual evaluation is being done?  Is SQL ignoring the condition?

That's kind of what I want:  For SQL **not** to do anything with `law.emp` unless `@Name` is numeric.  (I have other conditions that will use the `@Name` variable if it is text.)

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
law.emp = NULL
```

always returns `NULL`.  In a `where` clause, this is treated as false, and the row is not included in the result set.

I much prefer an explicit conversion:

```
law.emp = try_convert(int, @Name)
```

Or to whatever type `emp` is.

Comment: I'm trying to create a condition where, if `@Name` is not numeric, then different columns will be filtered (lname, fname).  What if `law.emp` actually contained a `null` value?  You're saying that `law.emp = NULL` evaluates to "false", and essentially, that condition is skipped?

Comment: @raydlevel5 . . . Yes.  Even `NULL = NULL` evaluates to `NULL` and is filtered out.